# VLOOKUP and COUNTIF issue - how to combine them?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, countif

I am stuck on this formula and I need help.

I have a column with different values (names of websites) and I need a formula that will, firstly, count them all and show me the total number of sites (COUNTIF) and then I need all that to picked up by a VLOOKUP column so I can make an automated chart.

Here's what I have so far:

=COUNTIF(D2:D,"*",VLOOKUP(Y2,C2:D,2,FALSE))

The issue is that I don't know how to combine these properly and when I do it like this, I get: "Wrong number of arguments to COUNTIF. Expected 2 arguments, but received 3 arguments."

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: First, of all what value Y2 has? Secondly, Although your question is not very clear to me but, I think you need to use Pivot Table to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: First, of all what value Y2 has? Secondly, Although your question is not very clear to me but, I think you need to use Pivot Table to achieve what you are looking for.